# Data Explorer data hasn't been updated for at least three weeks

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

It's currently been about 3 weeks since the last data migration to data.stackexchange.

The [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) says that data is updated weekly. Why hasn't that been happening?

Surely this should be an automated process, run by crontab?!

Comment: It's supposed to be updated weekly, but this hasn't been happening since Data Explorer moved, so this is a bug.

Comment: bug as well as Feature-request :)

Comment: It's not updated automatically, dev has to do it manually. I saw Nick saying this somewhere.

Comment: @azi - A bug request!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The process is automated now, after Nick cleaned it up some months ago.

Comment: @Tim so it got broken in the latest codebase update. Great, now we have to wait another 10 months for the next codebase update. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I assume it's not working because of the move from Oregon to NY, but I don't know if the automatic process being disabled is temporarily intentional or not.

Comment: Server moves are fun! :D  ... :p

Comment: @Tim oh well, we'll know is 6 to 8 weeks. :)

Comment: It looks like someone kicked off the job, so the data is currently backfilling (only a few sites left to update)

Comment: @Bohemian Surely this should be a *manual* process so the cron won't fall offline!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, yeah this was busted on 2 levels.  The part where the job crashed and burned annnnnnd the part that emails me telling me that, double fail.

It's working now, should be about 2 hour for SO to finish a refresh.  After that finishes, it will run weekly on Sundays.

Comment: Awesome! So does this fix the performance problems I [mentioned here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1446236#1446236)?

Comment: Send email: Job crashed; Send email: Email failed; Send email: Email failed; Send email: Email failed

Comment: I've been there myself... :/

Comment: @Nick Craver Any updates on this? The data explorer is still pretty unusable. Every single non-trivial query times out and has been doing so since it moved back to New York.

Comment: @Mysticial we simply don't have good hardware in NY for this, it's on it's own server out in Oregon, we'll get it back out there soon as we can.

Comment: @NickCraver Ah. Thanks for the info. No rush though, since I was just looking for some closure on this.

Comment: Are the [edits that vanished in the move](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10386877#10386877) lost forever?